# How can I align bootstrap 4 columns to stay side-by-side on smaller screens?

Tags: css, html, grid, bootstrap-4

I have a row and 2 columns on large screen. I am trying to maintain the the 2 columns being aligned next to each other on smaller screen. Say, 768px.

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6">
<p> This is just a test</p>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
<p> This is just a test</p>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please read the [Bootstrap docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#grid-options)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want them to always be side by side, just use col:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col">
        <p> This is just a test</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        <p> This is just a test</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Applying a number to the "col" will require the column to be at least a certain width (depending on the number). By not specifying the number, it will require the columns to be as narrow as they need to be in order to keep them in the same line.

Answer (score 0):

When you say col-md it's for medium devices you can use col-sm for small devices. I suggest you read the documentation on bootstrap.

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-6">
    <p> This is just a test</p>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-6">
    <p> This is just a test</p>
</div>
```

Comment: This is tagged for Bootstrap 4, so the asker probably wants a solution for that version.

Comment: @Klooven you're right, I changed my answer